# How to place a URL link in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I need to place a URL link in oracle apex - blank region of a report.

I tried to place the link in html region of the report , but it is not working.

Can someone tell me how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a html region (Static content) you can use regular html.  So you can do stuff like (source in html region):

```
<b>Click here:</b> <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Stackoverflow</a>
```

and it will show up as a link

[image]

[image]